# How to avoid atoi when read a file

Tags: c++, string, file, c++11, serialization

I write some information on a file especially unsigned int.
Later another program go read these informations.
The problem is that this second program is very slow.
I profile it, It spend 50% of is time just to do atoi.

Is there a way to write the unsigned int on the file to avoid atoi
(binary? serialize?)

Ps: I use mmap for read

EDIT:

I see your response and the solution which look the best is to put the binary content of int in the file

Comment: Tried using fstream to read formatted input ?

Comment: [BOOST serialization!!!!](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: Are you minimising memory allocations by reading your data into a fixed buffer?

Comment: you _can_ indeed write (and read) the binary representation of an `unsigned int`.

Comment: PS: the file is mmap for read it

Comment: If this is a conversion speed issue, then definitely do write binary numbers. No one string to int method in the standard library is going to be much faster than the others. If there is nothing but numbers and they are all the same bit depth, you can get really really stupid about it. If there is any complexity to the information stored, I recommend establishing a file format that describes what goes where and possibly grouping the information to allow runs of data. Also consider compression. It's often a lot faster to decompress in memory than it is to read a much larger data file from disk.

Comment: Show us the code that's slow. It's likely that you're calling `atoi` way more often than you need to or otherwise doing something awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atoi() is still faster than using string streams. However, using string streams to do this is the ONLY way to be both type-safe and standard across C++.

The best way to be both type-safe AND standardized, yet also be faster than either string streams or stuff like atoi() or strtoul() is to use the conventions of the Boost library to do it.

The Boost lexical_cast is fast and typesafe.

Edit: 2:07pm 7/19/2016

In your case you can skip this completely if you write the file in binary mode. Something really back to basics like...

```
 ofstream fout;
 fout.open("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);

 unsigned int int_out;
 for(int i=0; i< someArray.length; ++i) {
 int_out = someArray[i];
 fout.write((char*)&int_out, sizeof(unsigned int));
 }
```

Then you can read it in on the other end pretty much the same way. But use...

```
 ifstream fin;
 fin.open("example.bin", ios::binary);

 unsigned int int_in;
 for(int i=0; i< someArray.length; ++i) {
 fout.read((char*)&int_in, sizeof(unsigned int));
 someArray[i] = int_in;
 }
```

Comment: I can't use string streans i have a long char * for all the file (the file is mmap), do you have another solution than to write the insigned int to binary add to get it with a cast?

Comment: Okay, I edited it with another way to do it in binary.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [strtoul()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/).
It also have the advantage over atoi() that this one provides error handling.